# Getting book details from Amazon by fuzzy matched title

Tags: php, api, amazon-product-api

I have a database containing a list of books in a library, which only has the title and author specified. I'd like to be able to find each book on Amazon.co.uk, so as to be able to provide a link, and possibly fetch the ISBN. I found this question [Getting product details using Amazon API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586086/getting-product-details-using-amazon-api) which would work except that the titles in my database won't necessarily match completely those on Amazon. If I type the title I have into Amazon, 99% of the time the first result is correct, so if I could connect to the API and get the book details via Amazon search's guess at the title, I would be able to retrieve the details. Is this possible, and if so, how could I do it? Thanks in advance,
yttriuszzerbus

Edit: it looks like the Amazon.co.uk Product Advertising API requires a huge amount of hassle to set up - I'll try other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the API from Amazon, you would need to open an account with them.  This would also give you access to all the API's needed to get the information that you want.  I must warn you, there is documentation and examples that you can use, but the documentation is lacking and can be confusing/ frustrating at times.  I use it for a similar task, but I search by ISBN, so I know it can be done.  Start here https://developer.amazonservices.com/ and good luck.  Feel free to contact me with questions and I will try to help out where I can.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I'll accept your answer ASAP. Unfortunately, I've just found this bombshell: To begin the enrollment process, you must submit a complete and accurate enrollment form. In your enrollment form, you must describe the application you intend to develop and use with the Product Advertising API or on which you intend to display Product Advertising Content. - my application is trivial and definitely doesn't have a primary purpose of driving traffic to Amazon. I think I'll try ISBNdb.com - it doesn't have as many features, but the API appears to be public.

Comment: Make sure that you look at the MWS infromation and not the AWS as AWS is going away at the end of August.  I am not sure about the enrollment form, as I took over this project after all that was done.